# vb2022 vb.net .net6 vb vbc.exe complie error exit with error code

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2022

I work with vs 2022 .net6 Visual Basic.
After a couple of days working on my perfectly fine running program ,it wont run anymore.
VB.EXE exited with errorcode -2146232797.
Error : **MSB6006**
I have not updated VisualStudio (to a buggy version) in the meanwhile. So the environment has not changed.
I found an old solution on how to install a good compilerversion (1.1.1) with the NuGet package command editor.But that is a 9 year old solution. And it does not help.

Maybe it is the imports?

I import :
IO,
Drawing2d,
net.http,
xml.
.

I desperately need help .
Can anybody help me?

Comment: Have you tried repairing VS? It may be that something is corrupt.

Comment: If you create a blank .net6 project do you have the same issue?  Will help to identify if problem is environmental or something in your project

Comment: Please provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) which others can use to re-create the issue that you're facing.

Comment: The following may be helpful: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/home?entry=problem

Comment: This is MS Build error, you could run the build and Turn Verbose logging on. shouldn't be hard to identify. One thing you can do when error like this does not give you info - clean solution, Even delete OBJ folder

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for all of your help. I have isolated the problem by commenting out all suspicious code, until the error re-occured.
The problem was the declaration "public const PI = 3.1415" inside a sub.
I cannot explain this, but declaring this constant outside all subs fixed my problem.

Comment: You may consider using [Math.PI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.math.pi?view=net-6.0) instead. The following may also be useful: [Access Levels in Visual Basic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/declared-elements/access-levels).